# Android browser (not Chrome, not all versions) has weird problems with z-index, absolute positioning

Tags: android, css, z-index, css-position

There are a few bugs I've seen logged about the Android browser and how it deals with absolutely-positioned "shroud" elements commonly used for modal dialogs. [Here is a **jsbin** example.](http://jsbin.com/ofigat/3).  Clicking the "show" button on a reasonable browser should show a little box with an "Ok" button.  The HTML:

```
  <div id=content>
    <button type=button>Show</button>
    <p>
    This is the contents of the page.
    <p>
    This is the contents of the page.
    <p>
    This is the contents of the page.
    <p>
    This is the contents of the page.
    <p>
    This is the contents of the page.
    <p>
    This is the contents of the page.
    <p>
    This is the contents of the page.
</div>

<div id=shroud>
</div>
<div id=frame>
    This is a frame.
    <button type=button>Ok</button>
</div>
```

The JavaScript just hides and shows the "frame" `<div>`:

```
$(function() {
  $('body')
    .on('click', '#content button', function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      $('#frame, #shroud').show();
    })
      .on('click', '#frame button', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $('#frame, #shroud').hide();
      });
});
```

And the CSS is just some simple positioning. The main content, the shroud, and the frame all have "z-index" values to explicitly stack them.

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(20,24,42);
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#frame {
  background-color: #e2f0fa;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

#shroud {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#frame {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px; left: 20px;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #336699;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f0f2f9;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

So the problem I noticed on Android 4.0.3 and 4.1 is that the little "frame" box just doesn't show up at all.  The shoud `<div>` does, and *sometimes* I can "wiggle" the page with my finger and the frame box shows up, sometimes partially, and (I think) always *under* the shroud, even though its "z-index" is larger.

Now I'm not sure why anybody would use the Android browser on a newer device supported by Chrome, but somebody might I guess.  Has anybody else seen this?  I haven't even found a similar bug report; I've seen stuff about older versions having goofy problems with input elements "bleeding through" overlaying elements, but nothing like this.

I've tried that test page with some older 2.2 and 2.3 phones and it works fine. My HTC One X and my Nexus 7 however both fail.

Comment: So, without a working demo, it's hard to troubleshoot this, but have you tried adding position and z-index of 1 to the parent that shares both the divs you need to work with z-index?  Sometimes that helps.  Also, why do you have #frame declared twice?

Comment: @TammyJAnderson There is a working example. [It's at the link I placed in the first paragraph.](http://jsbin.com/ofigat/3)

Comment: Oh and there are two "#frame" CSS blocks because I was just hacking around - that won't make any difference however.

Comment: @Ridcully Thanks!!  I make that mistake in actual CSS sometimes and it drives me nuts :-)